# TypeScript / React: Setting value of input to event.target.nodeValue

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm pretty new to to TypeScript so I'm looking for a graceful way to solve the following issue. I have a state variable called `emailAddress` and the value of this variable is set by an input field. I also want the input field to get it's value in return from the state variable, as such:

```
interface MyState {
  emailAddress: string;
}

(...)

constructor(props: LandingProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        emailAddress: "",
    }
}

(...)

<input 
type="text" 
placeholder="YourName@Example.com" 
value={ emailAddress }
onChange = { (e: React.ChangeEvent) => this.setState({ emailAddress: e.target.nodeValue }) }
/>
```

The issue here is that the value of the input field cannot be `null` eventhough the value of `e.target.nodeValue` can be `null`

Comment: `value={ emailAddress || "" }` should stop it from becoming uncontrolled.

Answer (score 0):

The solution ended up being this:

```
onChange = { (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>  this.setState({emailAddress: e.target.value})}
```

We missed the TypeVariable: `HTMLInputElement`